# Rounding irrational numbers

Tags: javascript, rounding

SO :)

I have some numbers. I want to round them depending on numbers after `.` sign. The problem is I don't know how much zeros will be after `.`.

I know functions `toPrecision()` and `toFixed()` but they must pass parameter. So I have to know how much signs I need to get after decimal point, but I don't know it.

What I want to achieve?

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ before            + after       +
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ 0.0072512423324   + 0.0073      +
+ 0.032523          + 0.033       +
+ 0.000083423342    + 0.000083    +
+ 15.00042323       + 15.00042    +
+ 1.0342345         + 1.034       +
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

How I can achieve this?

Comment: I don’t understand-how many digits do you want to round to based on *n* amount of digits after the decimal point?

Comment: so you want up to 2 non zero digits ?

Comment: @thecode16, to achieve what I want I can use `toFixed` function. The problem is I don't know param of this function. For each new number  I want to round this number is different. Thats the question. How to detect number of digits after decimal point in number to round it after with `toFixed(foundParam);`

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli Say, yes, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this:

```
function roundAfterZeros(number,places){
    var matches=number.toString().match(/\.0*/);
    if(!matches)return number.toString();
    return number.toFixed(matches[0].length-1+places);
}
```

Here's an explanation

`var matches = number.toString().match(/\.0*/)` checks for zeros (`0`) after the point (`.`).

`if(!matches)return number.toFixed(places);` if there is no point (`.`), it must be a whole number, so we just return it (as a string for consistency).

`return number.toFixed(matches[0].length-1+places);` if it is a decimal, we will round it off to the nearest digits after the zeros (`0`).

Then run it like `roundAfterZeros(0.000083423342,2)`:

```
0.000083423342 to "0.000083"
1.0342345 to      "1.034"
1 to              "1"
0.5 to            "0.50"
-300 to           "-300"
```

Comment: What's the `*1` for at the end? Presumably if the behavior is supposed to be similar to `toFixed()`, the result should remain a string.

Comment: Well this method worked. Looks dirty >_<!!!1 It is working without `*1` at the end too.

Comment: Ok.  I took out the `*1` to keep it as a string and added an explanation.  Sorry for the dirt :)

Comment: @SuperScript, I know about it :) thank you:) I will accept it if nobody wouldn't answer, don't worry :) Somebody can suggest better method maybe, right?

Comment: This answer didn't solve my problem. Look this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zYw32/ . Now try to assign `0` to `n` variable (or `0.5`, etc). `*1` will solve problem with `0.5` or `0.000005` numbers (2nd issue), but not with zero. I had already voted up your question so you have to help me :D

Comment: @SharikovVladislav : There's a version that should work correctly.